# window.event NULL in a click handler of a anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a KENDO UI Grid and in that in one of the columns I have anchor tags. Now when I click on the link I should show a popup with location determined by the mouse click coordinates.

When I try to access `window.event.clientX` I get an exception stating that `window.event` is `null`.

**Why is it null?**

At the same time I have another function for another column(using button not anchor) handler within which I am able to access the `window.event.clientX` field.

Can anybody throw some light on this behaviour?

Comment: You should post your non-working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.event` only evist in older versions of Internet Explorer. Other browsers and newer IE pass the event object as the first parameter to the hander function.

Comment: When I pass the event object as the first parameter, the object also shows up as undefined.